# How can I get value from one column in another based on a condition

Tags: pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, filtering

I have 2 columns A and B, I want to filter the data in the dataframe and keep the values of column A where it is 'A3' and the values of column A that have a date in column B.

so if it has a date in column B then keep its data in column A

The first part of the code is working as follows, what can I do about the second condition?

`Df = Data[Data["Reason"].isna(['A3'])]`   ....?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: 'a', 1: 'a3', 7: 'a3', 8: 'a3', 9: 'a9'},  'B': {2: '2018-05-01', 3: '2018-05-02', 4: '2018-07-05', 5: '2018-11-02',6: '2019-01-02',1: '-13'}})
```

df

I think there was a bit of confusion without data.

I want to keep all the a3 rows in column A is irrelevant of any condition in column B. (see above code)

The empty rows in column A have a date in column B. So I want to keep those empty ones in A based on value of B and fill it with a value like B3.

So when I analyze, A3 will mean accepted and B3 will mean rejected. So both a3 and b3 in one column

Comment: please share a sample of the data, and the expected output

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want all rows where column B isn't empty and all those rows where column B is empty but it has "A3" in column A.

```
# First lets take all rows where Column A is "A3" but column B is empty.
a3_data = Data[Data["ColumnA"].isna(['A3']) & Data["Column B"].isnull()]

# Then we take all rows where column B is empty
data_without_date = df[df["Column B"].astype(bool)]

# And in the end we combine these two data frames
final_data = data_without_date.append(a3_data)
```

Comment: please see my edit above